# Using loops to find multiple values in a single column of a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am fairly new to python and am working with a dataframe with millions of rows. I have a time series with fluctuating values and need to identify the rows with certain values. Specifically, I am searching for every time point that the value goes above 50. I know I need to create a loop to identify the rows where the current value is > 50 and the previous value is <= 50 but I am struggling with the syntax.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUYrd.png)

Additionally, I then need to take these rows and build a new dataframe.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

I was able to identify and extract the first value > 50 using the code below, but I need to keep looping through the column.

```
test = test_df.sort_values(by=['Time','Value'])
x = test.loc[test['Value'] > 50].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no actual question here, plus the title is awfully vague, and you don't actually need to write a loop for this ([looping is an antipattern in Pandas anyway](/a/55557758/4518341)), so, if I could suggest a better title: *"How do I find rows where a threshold is exceeded?"* See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: @Toyota [Don't use code formatting for non-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/4518341)

Comment: Also, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341), post the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you cah use `pd.Series.shift()` to create the mask:

```py
mask = (df["Value"] > 50) & (df["Value"].shift() <= 50)
print(df[mask])
```

Prints:

```
                   Time  Value
4   2024_03_05_13_25_53     62
11  2024_03_05_13_26_00     67
```